# How does $\frac{1}{x+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(x^n)$ follow from a Taylor expansion at $x = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

My question is as follows:

> (g) Show that Taylor's series for the function $f$ in terms of $t$, where
>
> $$f(t) = \frac{1}{(t+1)}$$
>
> in the vicinity of $t=1$, is given by
>
> $$\begin{align}f(t) = \frac{1}{(t+1)} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n t^n \\ &= 1 - t + t^2 - t^3 + t^4 + \cdots \end{align}$$

I have shown by induction that for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$,the $n^{th}$ derivative is

$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x+1)^{n+1}}$$

Plugging this result into the Taylor series expansion for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$ at $x=1$,

$$\frac{1}{x+1} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(x)\bigg|_{x=1} (x-1)^n $$

I have simplified the expression into

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}} (x-1)^n$$

I was expecting the expression to simplify into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{n}$, but I am not getting anywhere.

How do I continue from here to get the expected expression, without using Maclaurin Series?

Comment: If you want a series in $x$, rather than in $x-1$, why are you looking at the Taylor expansion at $x=1$ rather than at $x=0$? Also, you have a typo in your title, I believe.

Comment: I am bounded by the condition that I have to use the Taylor series at x=1 for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$

Comment: Then you're never going to get the expression you expected. The two series converge on different intervals.

Comment: I have added the original question that I have in the post. Perhaps it would clear things up?

Comment: The question is pure nonsense. Complain to your professor. For starters, the series converges only when $|t|<1$, not when $t$ is "in the vicinity of" $1$.

Comment: There is a typo in the question. Teachers are human too. As noted by  Ted Shifrin, you should develop the  Taylor series at 0 to get the required  series.

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will clarify with my professor.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, when $|t| < 1$, the expression $\dfrac{1}{1 - t}$ can be expressed as the limit of a geometric series.  I (personally) am unfamiliar with the relationship between what I am about to detail, and Taylor Series.  However, the Math (shown below) is undeniable.

Consider the product

$$(1 - t)(1 + t + t^2 + \cdots + t^n) = \left[1 - t^{(n+1)}\right]. \tag1 $$

Let $S(n)$ denote the *partial sum* of

$$(1 + t + t^2 + \cdots + t^n).$$

Then, for **any**  value of $t$ such that $t \neq 1$, you have that

$$S(n) = \frac{1 - t^{(n+1)}}{1 - t} = \frac{1}{1 - t} + \frac{E(n)}{1 - t} ~: ~E(n) = -t^{(n+1)}.$$

It is easy to see that for **fixed** $t$ such that $0 < t < 1$, you have that $\log(t)$ is some fixed negative number.  Therefore, $\log\left[t^{(n+1)}\right] = (n+1) \times ~$ some fixed negative number.

Therefore, for **fixed** $t$ such that $0 < t < 1$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} E(n) = 0.$$

Consideration of $t$ such that $-1 < t < 0$ is similar, because you can let $r = -t \implies 0 < r < 1.$

Then, the sequence $t^1, t^2, t^3, t^4,\cdots$ is identical to the sequence 
$-r^1, r^2, -r^3, r^4, \cdots.$

So, since the sequence $r^1, r^2, \cdots$ goes to $(0)$, so does the sequence $t^1, t^2, \cdots$.

What the above discussion demonstrates is that for any $t$ such that $-1 < t < 1$, you have that

the infinite geometric series $1 + t + t^2 + \cdots$ is convergent, and converges to the value

$$\frac{1}{1-t}.$$

---

The posted question, which **bizarrely** discusses $\dfrac{1}{1+t}$ in the **vicinity (??)** of $1$ may be restated as follows:

Suppose that $t$ is **any** negative number such that $-1 < t < 0.$  
Let $r = -t \implies 0 < r < 1$.

Then, from the previous discussion,

$$\frac{1}{1 + t} = \frac{1}{1 - r} = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots$$

$$= 1 - t + t^2 - t^3 + \cdots - \cdots $$

Answer (score 0):

A sort of TL; DR to above answer:
If you accept that,  for |r|<1, the sum $$S(r):= 1+ r+ r^2+ ...+ r^n+...$$
Converges to $$ \frac {1}{1-r} $$,
Then $\frac{1}{1-x }$ is just the expression above corresponds to $S(-x) $

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote. Apologies for my being unable to read your mind. Pasive-Aggressiveness rules! At least for some,  I guess.